# Problem with data gaps in Wavelet analysis in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run the analyze.wavelet function from WaveletComp package with a time series with 15 years of data. There are some small gaps in the data resulting in error "Some values in your time series seem to be missing." Is there a way to analyze the time series as a single block? I would prefer that in my work instead of data separated to several blocks. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not aware of any wavelet transform implementations for `R` that allow missing data. Depending on your application, mean-normalizing and replacing missing values with either zeros or some kind of imputation/interpolation function may be sufficient.